# regex whole word option

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem about matching whole words in java, what I want to do is finding the start indices of each word in a given line

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("("+str+")\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
if(matcher.find()){
    //Doing something 
}
```

I have a problem with this given case

```
line = "Watson has Watson's items.";
str = "watson";
```

I want to match with only the first watson here without matching the other one and i dont want my pattern to have some empty space control, what should i do in this case

Comment: Could you clarify *i dont want my pattern to have some empty space control* please? What is your requirement for a *word* and its allowed *context*? You know, you can append a lookahead like `(?!')` to disallow apostrophes after whole words.

Comment: if you want the start index of the first `watson`, why don´t you use the `String#indexOf` function for it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew apostrophes are only an example. I want to check - , + or any other non-word characters

Comment: @KevinEsche because if it contains 2 watson words i want to get both of them in matcher groups

Comment: An apostrophe is a non-word character. What is your requirement for a word and what context is allowed? It is clear you cannot use plain `\b`. How do you want to restrict it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i already used \b but when i search for (watson)\b it also matches the watson it the watson's watson+this watson-edison and so. I want it to only match the plain watson

what i want to do is using a pattern like (watson) and looking ahead to not to find any other non word characters

Comment: Don't use word boundary. Use: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s|^)" + str + "(?=\\s|$)");` to use space as word delimiter.

Comment: Well, I also though about a similar approach as @anubhava, like `"(?<!\\S)" + str + "(?!\\S)"`, I just got confused with *empty space control*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with the empty space control i meant i didn't want to look ahead to check if it has empty space after it since the word may be the last word of the string

Comment: I added an answer, please check my idea. I suggest checking for non-whitespace absence and also a suggestion for matching a word at the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word boundary `\b` matches the location between a non-word and a word character (or the start/end before/after a word character). The `'`, `-`, `+`, etc. are *non-word* characters, so `Watson\b` will match in `Watson's` (partial match).

You might want to only match `Watson` if it is not enclosed with non-whitespace symbols:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)" + str + "(?!\\S)");
```

To match `Watson` at the end of the sentence, you will need to allow matching before `.`, `?` and `!`, use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)" + str + "(?![^\\s.!?])");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC0dG4/1)

Just FYI: perhaps, it is a good idea to also use `Pattern.quote(str)` instead  of plain `str` to avoid issues when your `str` contains special regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

Use find() method in matcher

Refer [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--)